# Mongoose - Listen for events on bulk operations

Tags: mongodb, events, mongoose, bulkinsert, mongoose-schema

I am using bulk operations to upsert documents in my collection. After each such upsert I want to trigger a certain action.

I know that there are the `pre/post` hooks for mongoose models, however using "save" or "update" on those does not get triggered by the bulk operations.

Does anybody know a solution how to listen for bulk operations?

This is an example for my bulk operation:

```
const bulk = MyModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({someField: "someValue"}).upsert().updateOne({someField: "someNewValue"});
```

And my hooks:

```
MyModel.post("save", (doc: any) => {
    console.log("In save hook");
});
MyModel.post("update", (doc: any) => {
    console.log("In update hook");
});
```

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite: "This function does not trigger any middleware"

Comment: thank your for the hint. Do you have any ideas how I can achieve what I need, then? Is there any other way to hook into bulks?